# Repotting diseased chilli plants - possibly rust

Tags: diseases, chili, rust, repotting

My chilli plants appear to have developed rust after a bad attack from aphids! See photo below

[image: Rust?]

The leaves have also gone curly:

[image: Curly Leaves]

My plan is to repot the plants, washing away the old soil and replacing it with compost I bought. Would this help the plants? Or would the new compost just be infected with the disease?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The infection is in the plant so washing the soil would just stress it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chillis don't like you touching their roots, don't change the compost. Also it looks like you may have thrips as well, unless the leaf deformation is due to the aphids.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t see any pesticides to cure this issue! So we do local pesticides by ourselves.

2.5 kg of Neem leaves,
20 kg of green or red chili.

Blend the leaves with little water and  strain and get its liquid.
Then blend with chilies repeat the same.
Add them all in a 1 liter water container and keep over night covered with a lid.

In the morning add 20 liter of water
And add 2 table spoon of detergent.
Mix well and let it strain again
ready to spray.

Please try it. It can be used for many pests, including mosaic virus.

Comment: Using 20 kgs of chilli to treat a few chilli plants is maybe not a way to go here :). A small amount of Neem oil mixed with water and dishsoap would be just fine to treat both aphids and thrips on the plant in the question. On a larger number of plants maybe but note that Neem leaves can be hard to come by at many places.